# Unity 5 - edit the camera2DFollow script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using the standard `camera2DFollow` script that comes with Unity 5. But I have a problem with the position of the camera. I've rotated my main camera and it looks like this now.

[image: Example]

You see that my player is on top of the screen instead of the middle.

This is the default script in C# for the people who don't have it.

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

namespace UnityStandardAssets._2D
{
public class Camera2DFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    public float damping = 1;
    public float lookAheadFactor = 3;
    public float lookAheadReturnSpeed = 0.5f;
    public float lookAheadMoveThreshold = 0.1f;

    private float m_OffsetZ;
    private Vector3 m_LastTargetPosition;
    private Vector3 m_CurrentVelocity;
    private Vector3 m_LookAheadPos;

    // Use this for initialization
    private void Start()
    {
        m_LastTargetPosition = target.position;
        m_OffsetZ = (transform.position - target.position).z;
        transform.parent = null;
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {
        // only update lookahead pos if accelerating or changed direction
        float xMoveDelta = (target.position - m_LastTargetPosition).x;

        bool updateLookAheadTarget = Mathf.Abs(xMoveDelta) > lookAheadMoveThreshold;

        if (updateLookAheadTarget)
        {
            m_LookAheadPos = lookAheadFactor*Vector3.right*Mathf.Sign(xMoveDelta);
        }
        else
        {
            m_LookAheadPos = Vector3.MoveTowards(m_LookAheadPos, Vector3.zero, Time.deltaTime*lookAheadReturnSpeed);
        }

        Vector3 aheadTargetPos = target.position + m_LookAheadPos + Vector3.forward*m_OffsetZ;
        Vector3 newPos = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, aheadTargetPos, ref m_CurrentVelocity, damping);

        transform.position = newPos;

        m_LastTargetPosition = target.position;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to change the Y to a +3 of the current position. So if my camera is on Y 2 than put it on Y 5. (This makes it so the player is in the middle and not on the top).

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by adding 3 to the camera's position at the end of each frame but I recommend against it.

What I would do, is create an empty object, name it "PlayerCameraCenter" and make the player parent to this object; then place the camera center wherever you want relative to the player, like y = 3, and make the camera follow this object instead of the player.

This way you can easily change the position of the camera, through the editor without fiddling with code.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think about this! I'm a bit new to Unity